# Add right click menu item inside gutter of vscode

Tags: vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code

How to add right click menu inside the editor's gutter of vscode.

I want to have a provision to show/hide line numbers option on the right click inside the editor's gutter.

I am not sure about the extension point for this.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, this is not possible, yet.

I have [filled an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/5455), "OnClick event on Gutter #5455" sometime ago, but it is still open, and no Milestone defined.